# Make score go up by only 1 after collision instead of going up really fast because of continuous collision

Tags: java

Is there anyway to only have the score go up by 1 during the constant collision

here is the code I am using for collision

```
 if (Collision(object1, object)) {

            score +=  1;
```

Comment: Set something like `isColliding` during the first collision, check for it before increasing the `score` and reset `isColliding` when the collision ends.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a game engine, I would recommend looking into *Event Driven Architecture*. Best practice would be to create a special Event, CollisionStartEvent, which is only triggered at the first intersection of each new collision, and not during every frame of a continuing one.

Answer (score -1):

Make a flag to check if its the first collision, if not then don't increase the score